# Sanitize user input

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular and have a form that users can book a hotel. This posts to a 3rd party API.

I understand xss and ng-bind-html when the data is outputted back to the view but how do you strip a form or input box of malicious code before the form is sent to the API?

I know Laravel has a sanitize function that you can wrap in your model beforehand.

`$sce` and `$sanitize` from what I can see only deals with the view? Or does Angular handle this out of the box?

Comment: I think it's better to sanitize from server side. Not from client side. If you do not call the api directly from client side.

Answer (score 3):

It's best if you sanitize **both** on the client and server.

- **Server side because**: 
  You can't trust a Javascript client that can be modified through the     JS console of the browser. In addition someone can send a POST/PUT request mimicking your client using cURL.
- **Client side because**: faster response and first line of defense allowing you to sanitize and value or warn about it without doing a lengthier round trip to the server.
  You should be including the ngSanitize module and the angular-sanitize.js script in order for value sanitazation to take place automatically.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize
https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/learning/xss/#PreventingXSS